# How to label a object in tikz with an indicator line

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels

I would like to make some sets and label/name them with an indicator line.
The border of the set should follow some coordinates. I'm trying to get those red lines to the nearest (or some specific point) of the border of the object (a line or node). Here is my MWE and a picture:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \draw plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {(0,0)(2,3)(7,2)(6,-3)(3,-4)(1,-1)} node (a) {};
        \node [circle, left, label={[xshift=-1cm,yshift=-1cm]\large $\Omega$}] (b) at (a) {};

        \node [style={circle,fill=gray!25,draw}, label={[xshift=1cm,yshift=-1cm]text}] (c) at (2,2) {};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're after the `pin` option, instead of `label`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \draw plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {(0,0)(2,3)(7,2)(6,-3)(3,-4)(1,-1)} coordinate [pin={[pin edge={red,thick}]below left:$\Omega$}] (a) {};

        \node [style={circle,fill=gray!25,draw}, pin={[pin edge={red,thick}]below right:text}] (c) at (2,2) {};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]